# ComboBox selected item does not get set until SelectionChangedCommand's execute is finished

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, selectionchanged

I used this [article](http://nerobrain.blogspot.com/2012/01/execute-command-on-combobox-selection.html) to set up a SelectionChangedCommand that I can bind to from my view model.

Here's my view:

```
<ComboBox Height="20" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding NameCollection}"
          commandBehaviors:SelectionChangedBehavior.Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
```

In my view model's SelectionChangedCommand Executed method:

```
 private void SelectionChangedExecuted()
 {
   // The logic in this method can take up to 30 seconds at times.
 }
```

Now my problem is that when the user selects a new name from my comboBox, it can take up to 30 seconds until they see that their name is selected. It'll show the old name, until the SelectionChangedExecuted method finishes. Ideally, when they select a name, I want that name to show up immediately, THEN they can wait 30 seconds. Can I accomplish this with my current set up?

Current Behavior:
-Current Item in ComboBox: "Bob"
-User selects: "Steve"
-User waits 30 seconds, while Current Item in ComboxBox is still "Bob"
-30 seconds is over, Current Item in ComboBox: "Steve"

Wanted Behavior:
-Current Item in ComboBox: "Bob"
-User selects: "Steve", and Current Item in ComboBox is "Steve"
-User waits 30 seconds, while Current Item in ComboxBox is still "Steve"
-30 seconds is over, Current Item in ComboBox is still: "Steve"

Comment: What task are you performing in those 30 seconds? Whats with the 30 sec wait?

Comment: Loading lots of resources/objects into memory. 30 second is a worst case scenario. When I used a collection view, the selected item was reflected right away, and instead of using the SelectionChangedCommand. I would just listen to the current item changed event on the collection view. This worked well with this problem, but cause other problems. Now I'm attempting to use a SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're executing your `SelectionChangedExecuted()` method synchronously on the UI thread. You should do this asynchronously using `async` / `await` to execute your code on a background worker thread.

```
private static async void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Selector selector = (Selector)sender;
    if (selector != null)
    {
         ICommand command = selector.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
         if (command != null)
         {
             await Task.Run(() => command.Execute(selector.SelectedItem));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: using 4.0, otherwise I'd definitely give that a try.

Comment: Well, then you could try a `BackgroundWorker` solution (which I am not happy about) or `Task.Factory.StartNew()` without an `await`. In this case you will start your background task in the "fire-and-forget" mode. The point is, your long running processing should run on the background thread if you want the UI to response quickly.

Comment: I have a progress dialog during this long operation. It's just a matter having have the selected item update immediately. It waits until the action is completed until updating what's visually selected in the UI.